# How to ListPlot from Command Line In Math 12?

Tags: plotting, command-line

I almost always use Mathematica from the command line (Mac/Xwindow) and have things set up to plot/display graphics using Preview, which is great.

The problem is, *some* functions like ListPlot don't seem to use $DisplayFuncton to plot.  Is there some other way to get ListPlot to produce graphics from the command line?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it

```
$ wolframscript
Wolfram Language 12.2.0 Engine for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2020 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= plot = ListPlot@Range@10;
In[2]:= Export["plot.png",plot];
In[3]:= Run["open plot.png"];
```

Comment: Thanks I agree this works.   I already have \$DisplayFunction set up to work roughly as above, so something like 
 ListPlot]Range[5]]; \$DisplayFunction[%] also works.  But I would prefer to set an option in ListPlot somehow (if possible) so it uses \$DisplayFunction by default.  Not sure why it used to use \$DisplayFunction, and no longer does!